# SIZE LIMIT reached error in android?

Tags: android, video

I have a problem while taking video , after 8 or 12 second it shows an error "Size limit reached" , i use `MediaStore.Video.EXTRA_SIZE_LIMIT=9999999999l` and `MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT=90` in intent extra.
Whether it is device problem or have a problem in manifest or code need to be changed ah?

[image: This is the error i got]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your sdcard full? Post your video capture intent code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have enough free space on the sdcard?